# How do I create an array or list of externally managed objects in modern c++?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am building an add-in for a program. My add-in manipulates Ptr objects passed to me by the host application. I would like to create a vector of externally created and managed objects by the host. Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't have any clear examples of how to do this.

```
class Players {
    vector<Ptr<Player>> vectorOfGamers; // who deletes and when this? 

    public void CreatePlayers () {
    // call static application to create three players
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
       vectorOfGamers.push_back(Application.GetNextPlayer()); 
     } 

}
```

Confused about how to build this class and prevent memory leaks and causing a null exception if items are deleted prematurely. Also, how do I use modern C++ facilities to achieve this yet gain as much of the benefits of the new memory management like make_shared, make_unique, nullptr, etc?

For your information, below is a snapshot of Ptr.I am confused about the Ptr as it appears superfluous given modern C++'s new memory management facilities.

```
class IncompleteType
{
public:
    template<typename T> static void addref(void* ptr) { reinterpret_cast<adsk::core::ReferenceCounted*>(ptr)->addref(); }
    template<typename T> static void release(void* ptr) { reinterpret_cast<adsk::core::ReferenceCounted*>(ptr)->release(); }
};

class CompleteType
{
public:
    template<typename T> static void addref(T* ptr) { ptr->addref(); }
    template<typename T> static void release(T* ptr) { ptr->release(); }
};

template<class T, class PT = IncompleteType>
class Ptr
{
public:

    typedef T element_type;

    Ptr() : ptr_(nullptr) {}
    Ptr(const Ptr& rhs) : ptr_(nullptr) { reset(rhs.ptr_); }
    Ptr(const T* ptr, bool attach = true) : ptr_(nullptr) { reset(ptr, attach); }

    // casting constructor.  call operator bool to verify if cast was successful
    template<class V, class VPT>
    Ptr(const Ptr<V, VPT>& rhs) : ptr_(nullptr) {
        if (rhs)
            reset(rhs->template query<T>(), false);
    }

    ~Ptr() { reset(nullptr); }

    void operator=(const Ptr<T, PT>& rhs) { if (&rhs != this) reset(rhs.ptr_); }
    void operator=(const T* ptr) { reset(ptr, true); }

    // casting assignment operator.  call operator bool to verify if cast was successful
    template<class V, class VPT>
    void operator=(const Ptr<V, VPT>& rhs) {
        if (rhs)
            reset(rhs->template query<T>(), false);
        else
            reset(nullptr);
    }

    void reset(const T* ptr, bool attach = false) {
        if (ptr_ != ptr)
        {
            if (ptr_)
                PT::template release<T>(ptr_);
            ptr_ = const_cast<T*>(ptr);
            if (!attach && ptr_)
                PT::template addref<T>(ptr_);
        }
    }

    T* operator->() const { assert(ptr_ != nullptr); if (ptr_ == nullptr) throw std::exception(); return ptr_; }

    // Test if this pointer is empty (if operator-> will throw)
    /*explicit*/ operator bool() const { return ptr_ != nullptr; }

    bool operator==(const Ptr& rhs) const { return ptr_ == rhs.ptr_; }
    bool operator!=(const Ptr& rhs) const { return ptr_ != rhs.ptr_; }
    bool operator<(const Ptr& rhs) const { return ptr_ < rhs.ptr_; }


    // Iteration support.  Only usable if T has count and item members and an iterable_type
    typedef Iterator<T, PT> iterator;
    iterator begin() const { return Iterator<T, PT>(*this); }
    iterator end() const { return Iterator<T, PT>(*this, true); }

    // Caution the following functions if used incorrectly can cause a reference count leak
    T* get() const { return ptr_; }
    T* detach() { T* t = ptr_; ptr_ = nullptr; return t; }

private:

    T* ptr_;
};
```

Comment: Which CAD program?  Plugins will have specific requirements issued by the program.  See the documentation for the program.

Comment: I should have never mentioned CAD.  That;s not the point of my question.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't attach when you copy from another object. **This is very suspicious!**

Comment: Can you change both sides or your code has to adapt to existing program. If you cannot or do not want to change it, then C++ 11 smart pointers won't be very useful to you... Neverthless, you should verify suspicious code as noted in my previous comment.

Comment: I figured it out. I am not sure how the memory is precisely managed, but it appears it is just a DIY smart pointer.  Why did they go through this effort is a mystery. I guess it's like people who write their own classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re probably right that `Ptr` wouldn’t be needed in a post-C++03 environment. Probably your plugin API is old enough that C++11 wasn’t around back then. From the code you posted my best guess is that `Ptr` is supposed to be a reference counted smart pointer that manages shared ownership like `std::shared_ptr` does.

How exactly you use that thing should become clear from the plguin API documentation and maybe the source code of your host program. Just from the snippet you posted and without even mentioning the program’s name it’s impossible to say anything definite.